# Python: If / Else statement does not work when the condition is met

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

I am dealing with problem that my if/else statement does not work, when the condition is met.

The point is that I want to set my button ("submit") config to the **state=NORMAL**, when there is more than one character in entry area. I think the code is correct, but the problem may be caused by statics of the code. In other cases it requires the command (click, or other event) to be called, but here it is only change of entry content and I am not sure how to code it.

Below is the function with the button and my if/else statement. I am grateful for your help and every kind of advice.

```
def sign():
    infoLabel = Label(root, text="Enter your name: ").grid(row=0, column=0)
    global e
    e = Entry(root, width=25)
    e.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
    submit = Button(root, text="Submit", command=signbtn)
    submit.grid(row=0, column=3)

    if len(e.get()) == 0:
        submit.config(state=DISABLED)
    else:
        submit.config(state=NORMAL)
```

Comment: Why do you say the "if/else statement does not work"? What is happening? What are you expecting to happen?
Also, it looks like your if/else could be better replaced by a try/except block.

Comment: @Keldron I think they mean that it always executes the `else` case, while they expected to run the case where `len(e.get())==0`.

Comment: Have you thought to examine what `e.get()` returns immediately before the `if` statement? If this is your actual code, you're calling `.get()` about a millisecond after creating the entry which is well before the user even sees the entry widget.

Comment: @BryanOakley that is exactly what I meant. I wanted the code to check, how many characters are there in the entry area. If there was more than one, the state of the button would become NORMAL. I have realized that the structure of code is wrong, but it seems like challenge to find out how could it work.

Answer (score 2):

Let's clarify something please. When should state be set to "normal"? When entry's area length is more than one (>) or greater or equal (>=) than one? I guess the second based on your code. Also, is that tkinter?
Now, on your specific problem, what I see in your code is that you create the entry and then, immediately and only once, you check if its length is zero. Since your check is in the function, it executes rightaway and nobody has edited that entry yet, so it is empty. Therefore, it has `len(e.get()) == 0` so it sets `state=DISABLED` no matter what happens afterwards.
Finally, you should take @Premkumar chalmeti's answer considering globals into consideration

Comment: Thank you for response! Yes, it is tkinter, and the code should enable button to be (state=NORMAL), when at least one character is in the entry zone. I will check the answer below. Anyway thank you! Next time I'll make sure to give all information. I'm new to python, so I cannot properly distinguish.

Answer (score 0):

@Martin to answer your question accurately, could you please dump what `e.get()` method returns?

Your code may break in some corner cases (if `e.get()` returns `None`, etc somehow you never know) so I suggest below snippet and some improvements I thought.

You can reduce the if/else to one-liner and is more readable,

```
submit.config(state=NORMAL if e.get() else DISABLED)
```

Also, you should avoid the usage of global variables whenever possible.

```
def sign(e):
    infoLabel = Label(root, text="Enter your name: ").grid(row=0, column=0)

    e = Entry(root, width=25)
    e.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)

    submit = Button(root, text="Submit", command=signbtn)
    submit.grid(row=0, column=3)
    submit.config(state=NORMAL if e.get() else DISABLED)

    return e
```

Comment: These are two maybe useful pieces of advice, but how does that answer the question?

Comment: It looks like your answer is to use `if e.get()) ` instead of `if len(e.get()) == 0`?

Comment: We don't know what `e.get()` is returning so far. I thought let python do this job. :)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your responses! the e.get() should return the input in my Entry, where the users name should be written. Next to the Entry there is a button, which I want to be disabled until user types at least one character. What is the reason, you would use return and how to use it in order to solve my problem? Thanks

Comment: Using return wouldn't solve your problem, it would make your code better and in the long run less error prone. Your problem is pointed out in another answer. Also, by "dump what `e.get()` returns" they meant "add `print(e.get())` and tell us the result".